# Eliminating Google Analytics Campaign Spam

Tags: google-analytics, spam-prevention

My Google Analytics campaign report has a campaign I don't recognize that I think may be spam.

How do I prevent Google Analytics from tracking campaigns that are spam?  I currently have a filter setup to only include traffic from my hostname.

Since discovering that unknown campaign, I've also enabled the feature to exclude traffic from known bots and spiders.

Anything else I should do?

Comment: You can use a view filter to whitelist known campaign names and excluding everything that comes with an unknown campaign namee.

Comment: If you already have a hostname filter that means this spambot is actually going to your website. I'd recommend looking into server-side spambot prevention for that rather than trying to keep up with them via GA filters.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a filter to exclude this campaigns:

Admin >> (Go to the View or do it in the Account Column) >> Filters >> Add Filter >> Select "Custom" >> Select "Campaign Name" in the "Filter Field" Dropdown >> Enter the Name of the Campaign

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to stop injection of campaigns from random people?  Manually excluding spam campaigns only works after I see them (so far there are just a few).  Including only known campaigns will work as long as I know every campaign our organization is doing and remember to include them each time.  It could result in lots of filters.

Comment: No thats not possible. Maybe you can find pattern in the Spam-Campaigns for example Pages, Countrys, etc. and exclude this stuff also. 

Another way could be finding a unique naming for campaigns in your organization for example: Campaign names Start with a specific letter or you send a specific  "keyword" or other stuff to proof, that the campaign is from your company.